# Bind query string params to model in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an app similar to `Google Maps`. I would like to sync my model with query string params.

What do I mean by this?

Suppose you have a simple map object. You enter the site and you get default bounds set in the map component. But when you change something (pan/zoom/etc.), I want your changes to be set also in query string for location sharing things.

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you the way I implemented it but I'm not sure if it's a proper way to do it though.

The idea is:

First, I add a hidden input to record the change of map object simultaneously:

`<input hidden id='hiddenMapValue' #hiddenInput>`

`#hiddenInput` is there for a purpose and you'll see it.

Then, every time map object changes, assign the value to this hidden input, for example:

`$("#hiddenMapValue").val(place.geometry.location).trigger('change');`

In your component:

```
@ViewChild('hiddenInput') hiddenInput: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit(){
 $(this.hiddenInput.nativeElement).on('change',  (e)=>{
  this.onInputChanged(e);
 });
}

private onInputChanged(e): void{
 //This is your changed location value
 console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

`@ViewChild('hiddenInput') hiddenInput: ElementRef;` is how you get a hold on hidden input `#hiddenInput`.

And no, angular 2 model does not record changes made by jQuery. This is an alternate solution to this problem, so far.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Using jQuery in Angular2+ code is really against best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Inject in your constructor:

```
activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
router: Router
```

To update the URL you can use:

```
this.router.navigate(
  [this.param],
  {
    queryParams: {
      queryParamKey: this.queryParam,
    }
  });
```

To subscribe to changes to the URL changing you can use:

```
this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
  // remember to add /:paramKey to your routing!
  this.param = params.get('paramKey');
  this.update();
});

this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: { [key: string]: any }) => {
  this.queryParam = params['queryParamKey'];
});
```

This way you'll be able to make sure that everything is specified in the URL, since all your changes are pushed and pulled through it.